# Command CodeSign failed with a nonzero exit code Xcode 15

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, xcode, macos-sonoma

I am trying to build my IOS app developed in flutter on my new mac. I am having following error while building my app in XCode or debugging on VScode.

**Command CodeSign failed with a nonzero exit code**

```
CodeSign /Users/Cristian/Desktop/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/webview_flutter_wkwebview/webview_flutter_wkwebview.framework (in target 'webview_flutter_wkwebview' from project 'Pods')
    cd /Users/Cristian/Documents/GitHub/bahidora_app/ios/Pods
    
    Signing Identity:     "-"
    
    /usr/bin/codesign --force --sign - --timestamp\=none --generate-entitlement-der /Users/Cristian/Desktop/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/webview_flutter_wkwebview/webview_flutter_wkwebview.framework

/Users/Cristian/Desktop/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/webview_flutter_wkwebview/webview_flutter_wkwebview.framework: resource fork, Finder information, or similar detritus not allowed
Command CodeSign failed with a nonzero exit code
```

I tried cleaning, restarting the xcode, cleaning derived data folder, creating new a certificate and many more suggestions i founded but nothing solved this issue yet. Can anyone help in solving this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue. You must have also added your Desktop files to iCloud Drive - `moving the project folder from cloud` would solve this problem